# Summernote with jquery-steps

Tags: jquery, wizard, summernote

Trying to implement [summernote editor](http://summernote.org/) into wizard form which uses [jquery steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) and get a second text area. 
I'm not good at js, may it be any scripts conflict?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please add some details to your question? What do you want to achieve? And what have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple actually. Use this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example-basic").steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        autoFocus: true
    });

    $('#summernote').summernote({
     height: 300,
     minHeight: null, 
     maxHeight: null, 
     focus: true
    });
});
```

```css
.wizard,.tabcontrol {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}

.wizard a,.tabcontrol a {
    outline: 0
}

.wizard ul,.tabcontrol ul {
    list-style: none!important;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}

.wizard ul>li,.tabcontrol ul>li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0
}

.wizard>.steps .current-info,.tabcontrol>.steps .current-info {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em
}

.wizard>.content>.title,.tabcontrol>.content>.title {
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em
}

.wizard>.steps {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%
}

.wizard.vertical>.steps {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 30%
}

.wizard>.steps .number {
    font-size: 1.429em
}

.wizard>.steps>ul>li {
    width: 25%
}

.wizard>.steps>ul>li,.wizard>.actions>ul>li {
    float: left
}

.wizard.vertical>.steps>ul>li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%
}

.wizard>.steps a,.wizard>.steps a:hover,.wizard>.steps a:active {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 .5em .5em;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px
}

.wizard>.steps .disabled a,.wizard>.steps .disabled a:hover,.wizard>.steps .disabled a:active {
    background: #eee;
    color: #aaa;
    cursor: default
}

.wizard>.steps .current a,.wizard>.steps .current a:hover,.wizard>.steps .current a:active {
    background: #2184be;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: default
}

.wizard>.steps .done a,.wizard>.steps .done a:hover,.wizard>.steps .done a:active {
    background: #9dc8e2;
    color: #fff
}

.wizard>.steps .error a,.wizard>.steps .error a:hover,.wizard>.steps .error a:active {
    background: #ff3111;
    color: #fff
}

.wizard>.content {
    background: #eee;
    display: block;
    margin: .5em;
    min-height: 35em;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px
}

.wizard.vertical>.content {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2.5% .5em 2.5%;
    width: 65%
}

.wizard>.content>.body {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 2.5%
}

.wizard>.content>.body ul {
    list-style: disc!important
}

.wizard>.content>.body ul>li {
    display: list-item
}

.wizard>.content>.body>iframe {
    border: 0 none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

.wizard>.content>.body input {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc
}

.wizard>.content>.body input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: inline-block
}

.wizard>.content>.body input.error {
    background: #fbe3e4;
    border: 1px solid #fbc2c4;
    color: #8a1f11
}

.wizard>.content>.body label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: .5em
}

.wizard>.content>.body label.error {
    color: #8a1f11;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1.5em
}

.wizard>.actions {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%
}

.wizard.vertical>.actions {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 2.5%;
    width: 95%
}

.wizard>.actions>ul {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right
}

.wizard>.actions>ul>li {
    margin: 0 .5em
}

.wizard.vertical>.actions>ul>li {
    margin: 0 0 0 1em
}

.wizard>.actions a,.wizard>.actions a:hover,.wizard>.actions a:active {
    background: #2184be;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px
}

.wizard>.actions .disabled a,.wizard>.actions .disabled a:hover,.wizard>.actions .disabled a:active {
    background: #eee;
    color: #aaa
}

.wizard>.loading {
}

.wizard>.loading .spinner {
}

.tabcontrol>.steps {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 6px 0 0 0;
    top: 1px;
    z-index: 1
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul>li {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 2px 0 0;
    padding: 1px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul>li:hover {
    background: #edecec;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding: 0
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul>li.current {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    padding: 0 0 1px 0;
    margin-top: 0
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul>li>a {
    color: #5f5f5f;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul>li>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul>li.current>a {
    padding: 15px 30px 10px 30px
}

.tabcontrol>.content {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35em;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
    padding-top: 20px
}

.tabcontrol>.content>.body {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 2.5%
}

.tabcontrol>.content>.body ul {
    list-style: disc!important
}

.tabcontrol>.content>.body ul>li {
    display: list-item
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
    .wizard>.steps>ul>li {
        width:50%
    }

    .wizard>.steps a,.wizard>.steps a:hover,.wizard>.steps a:active {
        margin-top: .5em
    }

    .wizard.vertical>.steps,.wizard.vertical>.actions {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%
    }

    .wizard.vertical>.content {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 .5em .5em;
        width: auto
    }
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
    .wizard>.steps>ul>li {
        width:100%
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 

<!-- include summernote css/js-->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.js"></script>

<script src="http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/jquery-steps/jquery.steps/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-basic">
    <h3>Keyboard</h3>
    <section>
        <div id="summernote">Hello Summernote</div>
    </section>
    <h3>Effects</h3>
    <section>
        <p>Wonderful transition effects.</p>
    </section>
    <h3>Pager</h3>
    <section>
        <p>The next and previous buttons help you to navigate through your content.</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

You also try my link with this example: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/jquery-steps/